# Perl script Lookup timestamp in a log file

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have to make a modification to an existing PERL script. As I have no experience in PERL Scripting i googled and made a change but that's not working.
So there is part that checks if a specific timestamp exists in the file.
the code is

```
    while (<IN>) {
      if (/timestamp="(\w\w\w) (\d\d) \d\d:\d\d:\d\d (\d\d\d\d)"/ {
        $NowDate=$3.$Month{$1}.$2;
        if ( $NowDate > $StartDate ) {
          print OUT $_;
          while (1) {
            $regel=<IN>;
            if (! defined $regel) {last}
              print OUT $regel;
            }
          }
       }
  }
```

- The timestamp in the log file = `Feb 15 09:28:13 2017`
- but after upgrade the timestamp = `2017-02-15T10:26:14.858`

i've updated the condition like this but it's not working.

```
if (/timestamp="(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)"/
```

Can anyone give me some advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( /timestamp="(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d"/ ) {
    $NowDate = $1.$2.$3;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't pass the if condition. the timestamp in the file is timestamp="2017-02-16T13:08:34.104"

Comment: You missed the fractional seconds from the pattern. Try now

Comment: I've entered the if condition but get the following error "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at". Do I have to use the /.

Comment: Ilhan: If you have copied what I wrote then that can't happen. I don't know what you mean by *"Do I gave to use the /"*

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.